# followbutton Vue button not visible in website

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I cant seem to see the button on my webpage

here is the FollowButton.Vue code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4">Follow Me Now</button>
     </div>   

</template>


<script>
    export default{
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

here is the app.js code

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('follow-button', require('./components/FollowButton.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

and the follow button is in my index.blade.php and here is the code

```
<div class="col-9 pt-5">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3">
                    <div class="h4"></div>
                    <follow-button></follow-button>
                </div>
```

but it doesnt show in my webpage why is that ?

Comment: doesnt work still doesnt show

Comment: `el: '#app',` Is there an enclosing `<div id="app">...</div>` in your blade? Do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: @kerbholz i read now about it, i was totally wrong, somewhere i read about it and keep it in my mind. Comment removed. Thanks for tell me

Comment: @NBlack No problem, wasn't sure myself and couldn't find it. Removing my comments too ;)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when I tried create Instagram and couldn't show the follow me now button. I restarted my PC and figured out that happens because of cache, so I tried the following operation:

- F12 and try to enable DISABLE CACHE as in the picture
  this worked for me
  [image: I had the same issue when I tried create Instagram and couldn't show follow me now button then I restarted my PC and figured out that happens because of cache and then tried followin operation -F12 and try to enable DISABLE CACHE as in the picture this worked for me]